# ASP.NET / VB - Storing multiple rows from db table for further manipulation

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a SQL 'select' query that returns multiple rows based on certain conditions specified in the 'where' clause.

I want to store the rows somewhere, most probably in some sort of collection or object, and be able to manipulate the data within each cell.

but I have no idea what collection/object will be suitable for the task.

so any recommendations?

sample codes or tutorial on how to store and retrieve the data will be helpful as well.

Comment: You could create a class which has the representative columns from your database table, then store multiple instances of that class, each representing a row from the database, in a `List<yourClass>` object.

Comment: Depending on what version you are using, you could use a DataTable.

Comment: @DarthContinent i suspect that asp.net/vb has a simpler, more elegant solution, something like an arraylist.

Comment: a `List(Of myClass)` **is** simple

Comment: If you want something more full-featured... consider IEnumerable, which only reads from the list when you actually use it -- this can help your webpages' performance, because it doesn't have to read the entire list, in order to give you the values you're currently using.   Also consider defining your own class, like `Public Class MyArrays  Implements IList  Implements ICollection  Implements IEnumerable  Implements ICloneable...`  To get started with IEnumerable, check out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223584/Implementation-of-IEnumerable-of-T-IEnumerator-Of

Comment: @acfrancis thx for the suggestion. currently trying out `datatable`.